# Why doesn't the form entry update after button click [JS]?

Tags: javascript, onload

I am writing a little script which should do the following actions:

1) a button click triggers a form to load.

2) an entry of the form is filled with a specific value.

My code looks something like this:

```
document.getElementById('formButton').click();
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('formEntry').value = "foo";
};
```

This script loads the form,but the form entry doesn't update.
I suppose that the problem is that the form entry hasn't loaded in the DOM yet, but `onload` doesn't seem to do the job... Any hints on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `document.getElementById('formButton')` won’t have been loaded. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this -

1) You have to put all of the document variables inside window.onload

```
window.onload = function() {
  var formEntry = document.getElementById('formEntry');
  var formButton = document.getElementById('formButton');
};
```

2) You have to change the formEntry when the formButton is clicked, so put the .value change inside another function like so

```
window.onload = function() {
  var formEntry = document.getElementById('formEntry');
  var formButton = document.getElementById('formButton');

  formButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    formEntry.value = "foo";
  });
};
```

or alternatively

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('formButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('formEntry').value = "foo";
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the button click to an event listener:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('formButton').addEventListener('click',function(){
    document.getElementById('formEntry').value = "foo";
  });
};
```

By calling the `.click()` function you just trigger any given click event listeners, but you haven't declared one, and thats also propably not your intention.